# How to get the current year using typescript in angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

How to get the current year using typescript in angular6

```
currentYear:Date;
this.currentYear=new Date("YYYY");
alert(this.currentYear);
```

> It shows Invalid Date

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try,

```js
 alert((new Date()).getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 36):

You can try this:

In the app.component.ts.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  anio: number = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

In the app.component.html

```
{{ anio }}
```

I let you a Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byvzum

Comment: Or simply `anio = new Date().getFullYear();`

Answer (score 11):

Since Year is number.

```
 currentYear: number=new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
year = new Date().getFullYear()
console.log(this.year) // output 2020
```

Answer (score 4):

> This one is so easy.

In the .ts file use the following function.

```
  currentYearLong(): number {
  return new Date().getFullYear();
  }
```

and now in the html use curly bracket to access the year number.

```
<footer class="deep-color white-text center">
<p class="flow-text">great company &copy; {{currentYearLong()}}</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is work for me

Answer (score 2):

At the import section,

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

At the ngOnInit,

```
ngOnInit(){
this.date = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY');
console.log(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY'));
}
```

Comment: this is an overkill

Comment: moment is a heavy library for something as simple. Check out `date-fns` or `dayjs` - https://day.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, we can get the year from date object using `getFullYear()`.

```
currentYear: Date;
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentYear = new Date("2017");
  console.log(this.currentYear.getFullYear());
}
```

Refer this page for all date object [methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: You are setting the year yourself and then retrieving it.

Answer (score -1):

use moment library:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'

moment().year(); // current year
```

of course you can use this code as well:

```
moment().format('YYYY'); // current year
```